# Prove that $\lim_{\infty }a_{n}=0$ then $\lim_{\infty }|a_{n}|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point the mistake :)

Suppose $\epsilon >0 $ is given,it exist

for $\lim_{\infty } a_{n}=0$
$$ |a_{n}-L|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

or

$$|a_{n}|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

For $\lim_{\infty } |a_{n}|=0$ it exist

$|a_{n}-L|< \frac{\epsilon }{2}$ or $|a_{n}|< \frac{\epsilon }{2}$

then

$$|a_{n}+|a_{n}||<\frac{\epsilon }{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2}=\epsilon $$

therefore

$$\lim_{\infty }=\lim_{\infty }|a_{n}|=0$$

Comment: What do you mean by "it exist"? Also, $|a_n|<\epsilon/2$ does not follow from the previous line

Comment: You should quantify which $n$ you are using.  Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $|a_n| < \epsilon$.  It's not going to be true for each $n$.

Comment: @Fourier I post a solution for your convenience. I can hardly follow your arguments.

Comment: @juniven Thank you :)

Comment: @ You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help. Start by assuming a fixed (but arbitrary) $\epsilon>0$. From here, you use the assumption that $\lim a_n=0$. According to the definition of convergent sequence, we can find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $$|a_n-0|<\epsilon.$$ This is equivalent to $$|a_n|<\epsilon\qquad\mbox{for all }n\geq N.$$ Now, observe that if $n\geq N$ then we get $$\Big||a_n|-0 \Big|=|a_n|<\epsilon.$$
Because of the arbitrariness of the number $\epsilon$ we can apply again the definition of the convergent sequence and get
$$\lim |an|=0.$$